Computing the adjoint of $-\Delta$
In B. Helffer's Spectral Theory and its Application, Remark 2.7 p. 16 the author is considering the two following operators

$T_0=-\Delta $ with $D(T_0)=C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^N)$
$T_1=-\Delta $ with $D(T_1)=H^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$

and is showing that the adjoint of $T_0$ is $T_1$ but there is something that is not really clear to me. He defines the domain of the adjoint as
$$
D(T_0^*)= \{ u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^{N})\colon \forall v\in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{N}) \text{ the map }v\mapsto\langle u,-\Delta v \rangle_{L^2} \text{ is antilinear and continuous on }L^2(\mathbb{R}^{N}) \}
$$
and observing that
$$
\langle u,-\Delta v\rangle_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}u\,(\overline{-\Delta v})\,dx = \left(-\Delta u\right)(\overline{v})
$$
where the last equality means that we are considering the distribution $-\Delta u$ on the test function $\overline{v}$, it follows that the condition appearing in the definition is that the distribution is in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^{N}).$
This last statement is not clear to me, why does it follows that $-\Delta u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^{N}) $?
Edit: I tried doing some computation and i figured out that, if $u\in D(T_0^*)$, then i can apply Riesz's theorem, which states that there is a (unique) element $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ such that $$\langle f,v \rangle_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)} = \langle u,-\Delta v \rangle_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)} = \left(-\Delta u\right)(\overline{v})$$
but it is still not clear to me how this imply that $-\Delta u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^{N})$.

I thought it might be convenient to readers to know the author of your reference, rather than having to click on a link...

@paulgarrett Ah, you are absolutely right, thank you!
